# How to convert curl -LO to a windows or groovy command?

Tags: powershell, jenkins, curl, groovy

I need to install kubectl on a windows node in Jenkins
https://v1-19.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/

I don't have curl installed and I'd like to follow that exact step to install kubectl

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.19.14/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe
```

Any suggestion? The other powershell command in that link doesn't work for me.
Edit: As mentioned in my comment I tried:

```
Invoke-WebRequest "storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.19.14/bin/…" -OutFile "kubectl.exe
```

However the script just run and never stops
The console just show:

```
[Pipeline] powershell
```

Comment: Windows 10 and Windows Server 2019 now come with `curl.exe`  (and `tar.exe`), so you can use your existing `curl` command - just make sure you specify the executable as `curl.exe`, not just `curl`, because the latter is a built-in _alias_ for PowerShell's [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) cmdlet. If your OS isn't recent enough, translate your `curl` command into the equivalent `Invoke-WebRequest` call.

Comment: Would it simply be: Invoke-WebRequest "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.19.14/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe" -OutFile "kubectl.exe"

It works in powershell but Jenkins just keep running and never stops

Comment: Your `Invoke-WebRequest` command looks correct; there's no reason why it shouldn't work from Jenkins, so I suspect that is an unrelated issue that you'll need to investigate.

Comment: Please add the (relevant parts of the) console output of the Jenkins build that never stops to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cmd + powershell

```sh
PowerShell.exe -Command "&{$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; Invoke-WebRequest https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.19.14/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe -OutFile kubectl.exe}"
```

plain groovy

```js
new URL('https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.19.14/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe').withInputStream{
    new File('/.tmp/kubectl.exe') << it
}
```

groovy without `withInputStream`

```
def url = new URL('https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.19.14/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe')
def stream = url.openStream()
new File('/.tmp/kubectl.exe') << stream
stream.close()
```

Comment: For some reason the powershell command runs without ever stopping.
For the groovy script, I'm getting: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods withInputStream java.net.URL groovy.lang.Closure

Comment: withInputStream is not a static method - are you sure you are using new in `new URL(...).withInputStream{...}`

Comment: anyway go to jenkins admin and allow this method call

Comment: i've added another option.

Comment: @Oplop98, BTW: by default powershell  is showing download progress that dramatically increases download time. try it with `$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'` option (i'v edited the answer for powershell).

Comment: I added this option, it's adding the .exe to my workspace within 30 seconds, but the script still run for 6 minutes

Comment: I am using the powershell plugin. I added the script in custom tool. It did the installation once (6 minutes) and now I can just call it from there in no time. Thank you !